# Not getting same key values through keystore

Tags: java, security, cryptography, password-protection

I stored private key in a file using keystore

```
 ks.setKeyEntry("kk1", pr, pass, cert1);
 //ks is obj of keystore,
 //kk1 is alias,
 //pr-->is private key,
 //pass->is the password to protect that key,
 //cert1-->is the certificate chain..
```

I printed "pr"(private key) while storing to the file.
I another program I opened the file and read the contents using method isKeyentry and printing Private key using getkey....

I am not getting the both(private key) values same...(password is fine because if it is wrong the file will not open)..What's wrong????
Does it need to be same???

Comment: You are going to have to show the two different outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to verify 2 key values with any parameter like hashcode,toStirng etc.
This is the method I followed:
I tried to encrypt some data using both the keys and verified if I am getting same data or not.Whle comparing use Array.equals() since we get byte array after encrypting.

I did this just to know whether I am retrieving the same key that I kept in a file using keystore.

Thank you....

Answer (score 0):

How are you measuring equivalence?  The simplest, safest, method I can think of would be to do the following:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
byte[] digest = md.digest(pr.getEncoded());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digest));
```